# How to get the non-ASCII letters from a file, without them being "corrupted"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know how to read the letters from non-ASCII encoding, without them being "corrupted".

Here is the recreation:

```
print(open("somefile.txt").read())
```

somefile.txt (saved as unicode)

```
čđža
```

What I get is something like this:

`ÿþ
~a`

How do I get the original contents of the file?

Comment: 'saved as unicode' doesn't really tell you enough to read the file properly, you need to know the encoding.

Comment: @pvg I'm not too good with encodings, so how do I check which encoding it is?

Comment: How did you create this file? Your typical text editor will show you the encoding. You can then pass it as a named parameter to `open`, it's in the docs.

Comment: I just like created it in notepad and when saving it, it said that I shouldn't chose the ANSI, so I set it to unicode. I didn't see anything else.

Comment: Download sublime or notepad++ or something like that, notepad uses bizarre terminology. Any serious editor will just show you the encoding on the status line.

Comment: Microsoft uses "Unicode" for the UTF-16 encoding of the Unicode character set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're opening the file as `cp1252`, you should open it as `utf-16`.

(`ÿþ` is indicative of the UTF-16LE Byte Order Mark being wrongly interpreted as Windows-1252.)

```
>>> open('foo.txt', encoding='utf-16').read()
'čđža'
>>> open('foo.txt', encoding='cp1252').read()
'ÿþ\n\x01\x11\x01~\x01a\x00'
```

On a unix system, you can use `file` to see what's in the file:

```
~$ file foo.txt
foo.txt: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with no line terminators
```

In Python, the chardet library is good for this:

```
>>> chardet.detect(open('foo.txt', 'rb').read())
{'encoding': 'UTF-16', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
```

Comment: I have only one problem with chardet, it says it's an invalid module. And when I try to install it with "pip install chardet", it says that the requirement is already satisfied and doesn't do anything after that.