# Parsing ini file with configparser gives configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError with 'ÿþ\n' as the first line

Tags: python, ini, configparser

I'm having problems with reading a variable from the [.ShellClassInfo] section in a ini file.

My ini file: (with an empty break above and below)

```
[.ShellClassInfo]

IconResource=\\some_text
```

The way how I read text from the file:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('desktop.ini')
file = config.get('.ShellClassInfo', 'IconResource')
content = open(file, 'r').read()
```

In the rest of my script I check if some text is in the variable content.

But before I can check this, the following error raise:

```
configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: 'desktop.ini', line: 1
'ÿþ\n'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you provided contains information about the first line having those weird `'ÿþ\n'` symbols.
 `ÿþ` is in fact a [Byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) of UTF-16 encoding. (Found it here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47205705/how-to-get-the-non-ascii-letters-from-a-file-without-them-being-corrupted))

According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read) you can specify the encoding of the config file when reading it as follows:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('desktop.ini', encoding='utf-16')
```